# Adding The Delete Option To The Right Click Contextual Menu?

Tags: macos, shortcut-menu

In Windows it is possible to permanently delete a file or folder from the right click contextual menu. The right click contextual menu in OS X, does not by default give the option to delete a file or folder in this way, only the option to "Move to Trash", which means you then have to empty the trash manually in order to delete the file or folder.

Is it therefore possible to add this option to the contextual menu, to aid quick deletion ?

Comment: Let's for a minute suppose this was possible to accomplish (which since it's software is certainly possible). What would you have happen if you deleted a user home folder or /System?

Comment: @bmike That could be a question for the site. I'll do some research....

Comment: @bmike Firstly would OS X allow the deletion of these....surely its far too dangerous !! (I'm assuming a safe guard mechanism is in place to prevent this). Secondly in terms of the System folder, this would only be deleted if a new one was created following an archive & install of OS X ?

Comment: Why not just [use the built-in keyboard shortcut](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254596/151730) for this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simplest way is to create your own Service and call it whatever you want to name it.

I created a service simply called `Delete Now` and put it in my context menu like I have done here:

[image]

### Make Your Own Delete Service

1. Open up Automator (/Applications/Utilities/Automator) and create a new Service
   [image]
2. At the top right pane, select `files or folders` in `Finder`
   [image]
3. On the left most pane, select `Utilities` and drag the `Run Shell Script` option to the workflow
   [image]
4. Change the "Pass input" field to `arguments`
   [image]
5. Pase the following into the shell script body

```js
for f in "$@"
do
rm -rf "$f"
done
afplay "/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds/finder/empty trash.aif"
```

6. Click `File` > `Save` on the menubar and give you service a name. Whatever you name it, is what it will be called

[image]

This will enable it immediately on your system. If you ever decide you don't want it, and need to replace this item, navigate to `~/Library/Services/` and you will see a list of folders called `{servicename}.workflow`. To remove the one you don't want, just delete it then in Terminal type

```js
killall Finder
```

This will restart the Finder and remove it from the context menu straight away. Otherwise, it will clear up on next restart.

---

#### Add Keyboard Shortcut

To make a keyboard shortcut for the Service you created, follow these steps:

1. From the Desktop, click the word **Finder** in the top left hand corner of the screen, then go to **Services** > **Services Preferences**
   [image]
2. Scroll down the list on the right until you find the service you created by name. In this example, you can see `Delete All` that I made earlier. Highlight it, and click on `add shortcut`.
   [image]
3. This will bring up a box. Make sure your mouse cursor is in there and depress the keys that you want to use to set the shortcut. In my example, I have used the combination <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
   [image]
4. Press <kbd>Show All</kbd> to save your settings.

---

#### Keyboard Symbols

To help anyone new to Apple keyboard symbols, here they are as follows:

**^** = <kbd>Control</kbd>
**⇧** = <kbd>Shift</kbd>
**⌘** = <kbd>Command</kbd>
**⌥** = <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd>

Comment: If you wanted to add a warning to the "Delete Now" function that I had created, before you drag the "Run Shell Script" option into the workflow, drag the "Ask for Confirmation" option at the top of the second column to the main working area, and edit the prompt. This will give you a two-step option in case you click it by accident.

Comment: This is the image when you add the confirmation dialog. You can change it as need to:

http://i.imgur.com/zciyUNw.png

Comment: Looks promising. Thanks very much for that detailed explanation.

Comment: Just fixed up the code. Was missing `for f in "$@"` at the start of it.

Comment: Appreciate the thoroughness of your answer.

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain additionally - how to bind a keyboard shortcut to this new delete service, so that one can press the shortcut key to quickly delete the file.

Comment: Yes. Top right hand of the Desktop it says "Finder". Click on that, select "Services -> Service Preferences". Click on the service you created (mine was Delete Now). Select "Add Shortcut".

Comment: This can also be achieved through "System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts" then on the left pick "Services" and on the right select the service by name and press the "Add Shortcut" button.

Comment: Can you edit that into the answer above.

Comment: Not a problem. I will do it first thing in the morning. In bed now just watching YouTube and about to fall asleep.

Comment: Why not just use the [built-in keyboard shortcut](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254596/151730), Option-Command-Delete?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

There is a service called [Delete Immediately](https://github.com/jtbandes/delete-immediately)

(through https://superuser.com/questions/10676/permanently-deleting-files-on-mac-os)

or you can make your own with Automator by means of the `rm` shell command.

Check also [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43577/can-finder-delete-a-file-directly-and-bypass-moving-it-to-the-trash).

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised it's not mentioned here, but **there *is* a keyboard shortcut for this already.**

It's **option-command-delete**.

This works on El Capitan.  I'm not sure which version of OS X it was added in.

---

This shortcut works from anywhere in Finder (which is what this question is about), and also from inside the Trash (which is [where I got the answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/220044/151730)).

Comment: As far as I can remember, it seems to me this shortcut has been there like forever in OSX.

Answer (score -2):

Windows simply says delete but that's not what it does. Every time you "delete" something you are actually moving it to the recycle folder. There are only a few circumstances when a folder will not be sent to the recycle bin they are as follows.

1 When you close out of something without saving and it hasn't been autosaved or saved before. 
2 If you cut an item then cut another item therefore over riding the cache.
3 If the folder is a temporary file.

The nice thing about windows though is that you can let the recycle bin build up without looking at an icon of a whole bunch of trash. I've got a terabyte hard drive I don't have to clear it ever 10 items I delete.

Comment: Shift-Delete on a Windows computer doesn't move the file to the Recycle Bin.  It deletes it.